# How to change the device owner on a Domain Joined Azure AD Device?

Tags: azure

I am attempting to roll out a Windows 10 Pro upgrade in the office of a small business. I set up a laptop with myself as the first user, then added the actual daily user, but would like to delegate admin rights to the user. According to the Azure AD site global admins and the device owner are automatically device local admins, but in this case the user is neither. Can I delegate this permission or make her the device owner after the initial domain join?

Also, I am using Azure AD Basic (no funding for Premium).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the goal is to make the end-user a local admin then have them be the first to join the device to the azure domain and it will make them a local admin while retaining the global admin rights as a local admin as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the owner of the device via PowerShell.

Add the new owner.

```
Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId <Device ObjectId> -RefObjectId <New Owner ObjectID>
```

Then remove the previous owner.

```
Remove-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId <Device ObjectId> -OwnerId <Previous Owner ObjectID>
```

You can find the device's "ObjectId" using the following command.

```
Get-AzureADDevice
```

You can find the owners "ObjectId" in Azure AD UI or via.

```
Get-AzureAdUser
```

Additional documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#devices)

Comment: Do these PowerShell command have to be run on the target device or can they be run in the Cloud Shell in Azure Portal? Trying the Cloud Portal, I get a Authorization_RequestDenied.

Comment: @john-yost You should not need to run these commands on the target device. I have not yet tried this from Cloud Shell, but I usually run these commands on my workstation to manage other devices in the organization. I would verify the user used to run Azure PowerShell commands is in the correct administrators role. See this [support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3072417/authorization-requestdenied-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-op).

Comment: You can run it from the cloud shell, just run Connect-AzureAD before you run them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the owner, I just upgraded the local account to Administrator through the usual Win 10 settings.